# Wordpress Hacked, script is injected into wp-emoji-release.min.js, jquery.js

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress website is hacked and its redirecting to deloton.com ads. I did some research but didnt get to the root of it. I got the js script that hack in injecting into my site. It replaces normal JS Scripts with its own code. Till now I found 3 js files (jquery.js, jquery-migrate.js, wp-emoji-release,js) in which it injects and I think the file is selected randomly. If it selects jquery.js than there would be two calls to jquery.js, one normal and another one with hacked code.

I am thinking its using wordpress hooks to register its script. I don't know where to look from here. Any ideas how can I debug and get rid of this hack.

Actually first I though my VPS got hacked so I rebuild it but after few days hack came back. Now vps is secure I think, root login is disabled and I am using strong alpha-numeric password.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too broad and, if it were sufficiently scoped, would be off-topic for Stack Overflow because it's not about programming. Perhaps superuser.com or webmasters.stackexchange.com, but read their help first to be sure.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the hack, though. Good luck!

Comment: May it is a plugin? Disable all plugin bay it helps...

Comment: yeah I tried that, even changed the theme and reinstalled wordpress from update section but its stil there

Answer (score 0):

Do you enable the access log on your VPS? If yes, you can see on it to know how hacker access and inject the script on your file. Make sure your install plugins & theme is secure also.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. It wasn't a hack but apparently my own ISP "BSNL India" injecting js script into non-https sites. Similar action by BSNL caught attention in 2016 when whey where injecting popup ads, now they are doing redirect.